# Removing some x_scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
          mean_math mean_read mean_science country
    1   -4.1976624 30.971633   -1.9381413     AUS
    2   -4.0193006 30.542376    8.7161472     CAN
    3  -21.8172403  9.638434  -14.6299379     COL
    4   -8.6399967 25.467815   -0.6883553     DEU
    5    5.4746023 53.493446   22.4550453     FIN
    6   -0.0951738 39.918658   12.1398932     GRC
    7   14.1162251 27.930612    8.2923826     IDN
    8    6.4402359 45.649534   17.5006916     ISR
    9   -6.4779173 20.323509   -8.1990175     KOR
    10  -1.0302412 26.280249   11.1133112     MAR
    11   7.5553361 25.145138    6.7470357     MYS
    12   0.1138526 30.203776    8.6622651     NLD
    13  -0.7025857 32.751286   -0.4696149     POL
    14  21.4963288 64.712999   41.3613420     QAT
    15  -5.9149028 22.572479   -2.8969491     SGP
```

Dataframe diff looks like the result above.

```
diff %>%
tidyr::pivot_longer(-country) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value, country, color = value > 0)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(x = "diff", y = "country", colour = "diff > 0") +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free_x") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c( -100, 100))
```

This code above is what I've done. and the result is the graph below.

[image: result1]

I'd like like to add some codes to make my graph to like this below

[image: result2]

I'd like to put lines on each graph like "result2" graph. ---> (sorted out)

Also for x_scale, how can I remove -100, 100.

Thanks

Comment: Try adding `geom_vline(xintercept= 0) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-50, 0, 50))`

Comment: @Peter, please post your comment as an answer ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)


diff %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-country) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value, country, color = value > 0)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(x = "diff", 
       y = "country", 
       colour = "diff > 0") +
  geom_vline(xintercept= 0) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-50, 0, 50))+
  annotate("text", x = -100, y = 1, label = "Boys", hjust = -0.1)+
  annotate("text", x = 100, y = 1, label = "Girls", hjust = 1.1)+
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free_x") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c( -100, 100))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

**data**

```
diff <- data.frame(mean_math = c(-4.1976624, -4.0193006, -21.8172403, 
                                  -8.6399967, 5.4746023, -0.0951738, 14.1162251, 6.4402359, -6.4779173, 
                                  -1.0302412, 7.5553361, 0.1138526, -0.7025857, 21.4963288, -5.9149028),
                   mean_read = c(30.971633, 30.542376, 9.638434, 25.467815, 53.493446, 
                                 39.918658, 27.930612, 45.649534, 20.323509, 26.280249, 25.145138, 
                                 30.203776, 32.751286, 64.712999, 22.572479),
                   mean_science = c(-1.9381413, 8.7161472, -14.6299379, -0.6883553, 22.4550453, 12.1398932, 8.2923826, 
                                    17.5006916, -8.1990175, 11.1133112, 6.7470357, 8.6622651, -0.4696149, 
                                    41.361342, -2.8969491), 
                   country = c("AUS", "CAN", "COL", "DEU","FIN", "GRC", "IDN", 
                               "ISR", "KOR", "MAR", "MYS", "NLD", "POL",  "QAT", "SGP"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>